# Cannot load members with Get-ADGroupMember but can with Get-ADGroup... why?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using the ActiveDirectory module for PowerShell and loving how easy it's making my life.

I'm struggling with one group, though.

If I use the code below, I get a nice array of all members in the group (I think it's all... looks like it.)

```
(get-adgroup "VMRCopy" -Properties members).members
```

However, if I use the cmdlet designed for this purpose, it fails:

```
PS>GET-ADGroupMember "VMRCopy"
Get-ADGroupMember : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
At line:1 char:18
+ GET-ADGroupMember <<<<  "VMRCopy"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (VMRCopy:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist,Microsoft.ActiveDirect
   ory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

I have tried to see which object is failing by using the first method, then iterating through the members and trying to "Get" each one, but I see no errors.

```
$Mem = (get-adgroup "VMRCopy" -Properties members).members
$Mem | % { Write-Host $_; $t = Get-ADObject $_ }
```

I have looked in ADSIEdit and I have looked at Active Directory Administrative Center, but I can't find anything that looks screwy.

Anyone have any ideas of a free tool or PoSh code that will tell me what is wrong with this group's members?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. When looking at the members of the group that fails with the "Active Directory Users and Computers" utility I get the following;

[image: AD Group Member Friendly Name Warning]

Reading the TechNet docs for [Get-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617193.aspx) I noted the following;

> This cmdlet does not work when a group has members located in a
>   different forest, and the forest does not have Active Directory Web
>   Service running.

In my case I had foreign security principals pointing back to users that had been deleted. Deleting these members solved my problem.

There does not seem to be any way to tell the cmdlet to just return members, with or without additional details.

Comment: I forgot to come back and post the solution, but you were right on.

Answer (score 1):

At this point the error you encountered indicates that the method the underlying object use (GetADGroupMember) does not exist. For me the problem is not in your directory  data, but in the state of the ActiveDirectory module was when you call it.

Do you reproduce it systematicaly ?

Can you try to open a new Powershell interpreter, import activedirectory module and test it again ?

Comment: It does kinda look like that, but I'm actually about to iterate over 5k+ groups and this is the only one that fails.  I really think it's one of the members that's causing the command to fail, but I can't tell which.  Maybe it's corrupt.  I had a couple other groups that used to fail and I found members from a peer domain that no longer exists in their membership. When I removed those members, the group started working.  Thanks much for your response, JP.